# Area 51: Comment link blocked by suggestion to comment!

Tags: bug, status-declined, voting, area-51

When I click on the "Not a good example" vote button, a box pops up suggesting I add a comment  explaining the vote.  Unfortunately, if the question has no comments, the box covers the link which must be clicked to add a comment.  So I sit there for however long the box lives, waiting and cursing at the patronizing developer who though I was too stupid to figure out that a comment might be helpful.

---

It was pointed out by our esteemed host that clicking on the little box (as with every other little popup) makes it go away, which is true.  But it still interferes. An experienced user will know to make the comment, so the box is not needed and an irritation.  And one who does not know the standard little box behavior may be confused.

An easy fix is to put the suggestion above the vote button instead of below it.

BTW .. how come a downvote on the standard sites doesn't get such a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just click on the `<div>` to dismiss it?

All of our little notify divs behave this way, and most have the text

> (click this box to dismiss)

or something of that sort, in it.

Comment: It goes away when I click on it.

Comment: OK, so I didn't click on it. I hadn't noticed the pattern, and it doesn't have the "dismiss" text", and I tried to enter the comment and was frustrated.